# Fastest sort of a list with alpha sorted first in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, list-comprehension

I have a simple list where the numbers are strings:

`simple_list = ['1','2','3','4','5','K','P']`

I would like to sort this first by alpha, then numerically.

currently I'm doing:

```
# Probably a faster way to handle this
alpha_list = [x for x in simple_list if not x.isnumeric()]
grade_list = [x for x in simple_list if x.isnumeric()]
# Put the alpha grades at the beginning of the grade_list
if alpha_list:
    grade_list = sorted(alpha_list) + sorted(grade_list)
```

I'm sure there is a faster way to handle this - I just can't seem to find it.

The result I currently get is correct `['K','P','1','2','3','4','5']`

I just wanted to know if there was a way I could condense all that down that would be more efficient than multiple list comprehensions.

Comment: What is the problem with this solution you already have? Is the processing taking too long?

Comment: Something like: `sorted(simple_list, key=lambda L: (L.isnumeric(), L))` which I believe is explained in an answer somewhere if I can find it...

Comment: couple of changes may be use single loop to filter off the values. you can then use `.sort()` which will be inplace rather than `sorted` which will create a new list.

Comment: Yeah, the processing is taking a bit - I'm just trying to make sure I'm being as efficient as possible. @JonClements I will try that. I was searching and searching but came up pretty empty handed.

Comment: Make a dictionary mapping between alphanumeric characters and their sorted order, and use `sorted(arr, key=lambda x: mapping[x])`.
In essence you are re-creating the ASCII table, which string sorting is based on.
Your next step is to create a hashing function which keeps this new sorted order in mind, which will allow you to operate on longer strings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can sort the list with a key function that returns a tuple of `str.isdigit()` test and the string, and if the string is found to be digits, convert it to an integer:

```
sorted(simple_list, key=lambda c: (c.isdigit(), int(c) if c.isdigit() else c))
```

This returns:

```
['K', 'P', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
```

Comment: Try with this as an input `simple_list = ['1','22','3','4','5','K','P']`